# Unpredictable result in counting pairs of integers

Tags: c

The task of the program is to count how many times there are two consecutive integers their value exceeds 40. So, the problem here is that the result of the program is way wrong.

To solve this problem, I tried το change some initial values and investigating the mechanism of the code, but I didn't notice any mistakes. The code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int a,i,e=0;
    int A[31];
    for(i=0; i<=30; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        A[i]=a;
}
    if (A[i]>40 && A[i+1]>40) {
        e=e+1;
    }
    printf("%d",e); 

    return 0;
}
```

The expected result if we enter the integer 41 in all of 31 places of the matrix, the result should be 30, while the result there is always zero (0)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need some kind of loop around the if statement, currently you are only checking one pair of values.

Comment: You have a couple of problems. First, you've not properly formatted the code so you can see how it's logically arranged. Second, you're properly collecting the information into the array, but you also need to loop through it again to examine the entries afterward (when you're trying to count them) and you're not doing so. (If you use this as a way to learn to use the debugger, you'll also learn how to solve these sorts of problems yourself by stepping through the code.)

Comment: `if` statement must be in a loop. And your loop must go from 0 to 1 less than the array size; because you have to stop this loop 1 index before the last one. You cant check last index and last + 1, so be careful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"if statement" must be in loop.
And, Please aware the condition of 2nd loop what I set it as '< 30' instead of '<= 30' because your program want to compare the next variable together as "if (A[i] > 40 && A[i + 1] > 40)".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int a, i, e = 0;
        int A[31];
        for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a);
            A[i] = a;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
            if (A[i] > 40 && A[i + 1] > 40)
                e = e + 1;
        }
        printf("%d", e);

        return 0;
}
```